# CSRF Token Mismatch in Laravel 10 Jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-10

P.S: I have seen the CSRF Token mismatch answers from many in Stackoverflow and I tried them all.
My problem didn't solved with all the existing answers. So, I had to ask a new question again.

I am using Laravel 10 with PHP 8.x and jQuery AJAX.

in my app.blade.php, I added

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

in my resources\js\bootstrap.js

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    } 
});
```

in my blade

```
<script>
let data = { '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
//Already tried '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(text) {}
})
</script>
```

In my response,

[image]

Can someone help me out fixing this issue.

Comment: What debugging have you done already? Did you check if the header gets sent at all? Is a token available in `<meta name="csrf-token"...`?

Comment: Yes, The token is available in the header of the page I am loading. I am also able to see the token in the payload. Still I am seeing the token mismatch issue.

Comment: You're already setting up your headers with `$.ajaxSetup()`, you should not do it a 2nd time in the `$.ajax({})` options. And with it in the header you don't need to pass it again as `data`.  Keep it simple, remove all the duplciation.